# VBA script to trigger Python and saving down xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, vba, xlsxwriter

I am trying to save the .xlsx file and using VBA as a wrapper to execute the python file. However,  I can validate that python code runs, but somehow .xlsx file is not saved. When I run the same python file via IDE, it saves down the .xlsx file.

**VBA code**

```
Sub RunPython()

Dim shell As Object
Dim exepath, scriptPath As String

Set Shell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
exePath = """C:\Program Files\...\python.exe"""
scriptPath = "C:\....\mymodule.py"
```

**Python Script**

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2),index=range(0,10,2),columns =list('AB'))
excel_file ='sample.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file,engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Data')
print ("file read")
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Does that 'excel_file' have a path?
Does Python use a current directory and automatically add it to Excel file name?
If yes, do you know how to obtain it and can you look for .xlsx file there?
If not, how do you check if the .xlsx file has been saved? Where are you looking for?
Does Python raise any error?

I am looking to the code mostly like a VBA user...
I would suggest to send a message from Python, containing the current directory path. Supposing that the .xlsx workbook path has not somehow been defined and the code presented here does not include that part. Theoretically it should use the same current directory, but I think it is good to be checked...